# Не клонирует репозиторий

Tags: git, github

Есть приватный репозиторий на github. Мне к нему дали доступ, сначала Write, а потом даже Admin, но на попытку клонировать по SSH мне упорно пишет:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

В чем проблема? SSH ключ только что новый сгенерировал и добавил в профиле. ОС: Windows 10. Клонирую через командную строку (Git for Windows).

Comment: Криво копируешь ключ и добавляешь в репозиторий. Смотри сохранённый в профиле ключ и копируй оттуда - из консоли может получиться фигня. И ещё убедись, что git использует именно его, а не откуда-то ещё, а то у каждой программы может быть свой гит со своими настройками.

Comment: @Qwertiy причем тут профиль? Я генерирую то на компьютере, а не в профиле. Если из блокнота копировать - тоже самое (я проверил).

Comment: Я имел в виду профиль пользователя на компе. ```%userprofile%\.ssh\```

Comment: @Qwertiy я так и сделал

Comment: @Qwertiy кажется я нашел решение. Я почему-то думал что можно ключ как угодно назвать, но когда я переименовал его в id_rsa все заработало. Странно.

Comment: Вообще-то он вроде под этим именем уже генерироваться должен?

Comment: @Qwertiy под этим, если при генерации в интерактивном меню не поменять его, как я)))

Comment: Нашел решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412964/using-a-non-default-key-name-other-than-id-rsa Можно задать любое имя, только в конфиге прописать потом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохранил ssh ключи не под стандартным именем id_rsa. Решается настройкой конфига в файле ~/.ssh/config

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
    User git
```